# difference in performance between static html and asp.net site without dynamic controls.??

Tags: asp.net, html, dynamic, static

i use visual studio 2012 to make websites now since i like the IDE.I want to know that if there is any performance difference between a static html website and a website in asp.net without dynamic controls...
thanks.

Comment: Please define "performance".  Do you mean page load time, server resource usage, something else?  What server infrastructure are you considering?

Comment: I meant load time, and almost any other lag.I use IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time waiting for a web page to load is the network latency.  Hardly any of it is latency due to the server dynamically generating the page (assuming the code isn't really bad).  So the answer is, no, there is no noticeable difference to load time between static and dynamic pages.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic pages are mostly connected to a database server. So your app should query the database and fetch data, then manipulate the data and render as html page as output.

So html pages don’t need those steps therefore html pages are always faster than any dynamic pages (not only for asp.net but also other languages).